# More featureful/standard(ish) alternative to Mercurial hgk

Tags: linux, open-source, mercurial

When I install Mercurial on my Linux box (which might be Debian, or Fedora) I get a tool called `hgk`, which is invoked when running `hg view`, and displays the revision tree for a repository.

Unfortunately, though, you can't select any of the text in there; it looks like custom code which simply did not have that functionality implemented.

Is there a similar GUI revision tree viewer in which you can select text, and feels more like a KDE/Gnome/etc. tool?

It must be gratis and open source.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/).

- Gratis & Open Source
- Available for Windows, Linux & OS-X
- You can select text in most areas of the GUI
- **Full** Hg GUI not just a tree view
- Multiple Repositories open at once in tabs
- Also show a diff of the selected file that is a member of the selected change set.
- Explorer integration on Windows
- Gnome/Nautilus extension
- Invoked as thg

Example *running on Windows*
[image]